# Boto EMR creation gives "Log Uri is not in the required format" error

Tags: amazon-s3, boto, amazon-emr

The following code gives the error message

```
EmrResponseError: EmrResponseError: 400 Bad Request <ErrorResponse xmlns="http://elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-03-31">   <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>ValidationError</Code>
    <Message>Log Uri is not in the required format</Message>   </Error>   <RequestId>1c3d0221-4420-11e4-a09e-5113f30a0036</RequestId> </ErrorResponse>
```

no matter sort of S3 URI I try. I've tried a trailing slash, s3n:// s3:// and all other combinations with no luck.

Here's the code:

```
import boto.emr

conn = boto.emr.connect_to_region('us-east-1')

job_parameters = {"log_uri":"s3n://shadoop/logs/new-log",
        "ec2_keyname":"XXXXXX",
        "availability_zone":"us-east-1e",
        "master_instance_type":"m1-medium",
        "slave_instance_type":"m1-medium",
        "num_instances":"2",
        "keep_alive":"True",
        "enable_debugging":"True",
        "hadoop_version":"2.4.0",
        "ami_version":"3.1.0",
        "visible_to_all_users":"True"
    }
jobid = conn.run_jobflow("test_cluster",job_parameters)
```

Comment: I think it should either be of the form ``s3://bucket-name`` if you want the logs to appear as top-level objects in the bucket or ``s3://bucket-name/prefix/`` (note the trailing ``/``) if you want them to appear in a virtual folder inside the bucket.

Comment: No, the bucket name is irrelevant. I tried all combinations. I had to note use a dictionary of key:values as parameters and just pass them individually.

Comment: Did you try ``conn.run_jobflow("test_cluster", **job_parameters)``?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get this to run I had to pass the input variables individually as opposed to a dictionary. The following code works:

```
jobid = conn.run_jobflow(cluster_name,log_uri="s3n://shadoop/logs/new-log",\
            ec2_keyname="XXXXX",\
            availability_zone="us-east-1e",\
            instance_groups=instance_groups,\
            num_instances=str(num_instances),\
            keep_alive="True",\
            enable_debugging="True",\
            hadoop_version="2.4.0",\
            ami_version="3.1.0",\
            visible_to_all_users="True",\
            steps=[hive_step],\
            bootstrap_actions=[bootstrap_impala])
```